# Spring Controller returns an empty object in Kotlin the values inside the object are public

Tags: kotlin, spring-restcontroller

I have a data class which is the return type of a controller, when I access the controller using a get request it give empty array. When I call the controller method directly it returns the data class properly

```
data class Response(
    public val result: ResponseResult,
    val status: Int,
    val message: String
)

data class ResponseResult(
    val isActive: String
)
```

When I try using another data class already present in the project it works fine, just doesn't work with the new data class

update
it happens only when the variable name starts with is, if i change isActive to just active, it works perfectly fine. How can I make isActive work?

Comment: Could you share the controller's code? Also maybe you're using GET requests on a server that didn't have your change?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the server part. I'm just testing on my local using gradlew bootRun and sending get request through postman

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.